# Maven Cargo ignores properties in pom.xml

Tags: maven, glassfish, maven-cargo

I want to deploy my application with Cargo, but Cargo just ignores the properties. I tried to give -Dcargo.glassfish.removeDefaultDatasource=false as an cmd option and It works, but with the properties in my pom.xml it doesnt, any idea?

pom.xml: (shorted)

```
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>

        <configuration>
            <container>
                <containerId>glassfish5x</containerId>
                <type>installed</type>
                <zipUrlInstaller>
                    <url>http://download.oracle.com/glassfish/5.0.1/nightly/latest-web.zip</url>
                </zipUrlInstaller>
                <systemProperties>
                </systemProperties>
            </container>
            <properties><cargo.glassfish.removeDefaultDatasource>false</cargo.glassfish.removeDefaultDatasource>
            </properties>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: JSF has no knowledge at all of maven or maven-cargo... Removed the JSF tag. Tags are for where the problem is, not what you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that your plugin setup is missing one layer of configuration.

I think it should look like this:

```
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>

        <configuration>
            <container>
                <containerId>glassfish5x</containerId>
                <type>installed</type>
                <zipUrlInstaller>
                    <url>http://download.oracle.com/glassfish/5.0.1/nightly/latest-web.zip</url>
                </zipUrlInstaller>
                <systemProperties>
                </systemProperties>
            </container>
            <configuration>
                  <properties>
                      <cargo.glassfish.removeDefaultDatasource>false</cargo.glassfish.removeDefaultDatasource>
                  </properties>
            </configuration>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

**See also:**

- [Cargo - Configuration properties](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Configuration+properties.html)
- [Cargo - Maven2 Plugin Reference Guide](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Maven2+Plugin+Reference+Guide.html)

Comment: You are godsend... (...and I'am blind.)